# Vector store mixed types of data in Rust

Tags: vector, type-conversion, rust

In the context of converting a infix expression to a postfix one, using the Shunting-yard algorithm. I want to use a vector to store the output, which would store both operator and numeric type data.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Operator {
    Add,
    Sub,
    Mul,
    Div,
}

fn main() {
    let mut output: Vec<String> = Vec::new();  // create an output vector
    let a = 2;
    let b = Operator::Add;
    let c = 3;
    output.push(a.to_string());
    output.push(b.to_string());
    output.push(c.to_string());
}
```

This above code of course doesn't compile, since the `to_string()` method is not defined for `Operator`. I see two ways to fix it:

1. Define a `to_string()` method
2. Create a vector to store references to numbers and `Operator`.

I think the second is the preferred choice, though I don't know if creating a vector of references will introduce lots of complexity.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's no need to use references; just store the numbers and `Operator`s directly in an enum:

```
enum Thing {
    Op(Operator),
    Number(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let mut output: Vec<Thing> = Vec::new();
    let a = 2;
    let b = Operator::Add;
    let c = 3;
    output.push(Thing::Number(a));
    output.push(Thing::Op(b));
    output.push(Thing::Number(c));
}
```

And then `match` on them when taking them out.

Comment: I see. Since enum are of the same size. Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that an enum takes on the size of its largest option. If your Thing also had an option that was a large array each instance of Thing in your vector would have a memory footprint of the large array.

Comment: can you give an example code on how to iterate on this vector and checking the type... thank you!