# cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'de` due to conflicting requirements for struct made of enums with Serde Deserialize

Tags: rust, serde

Why can I auto derive `serde::Deserialize`for my `WidgetValue` enum, but *not* for a struct made up entirely of `WidgetValue` fields?

This seems counterintuitive to me.

EDIT: For various reasons, I'm using the WidgetValue enum because I'd like to send different values through a function with the same type signature. See [Vector store mixed types of data in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40559931/vector-store-mixed-types-of-data-in-rust), [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957103/how-do-i-create-a-heterogeneous-collection-of-objects), etc.

```
serde = { version = "1.0.126", features = ["derive"] }
```

```rust
//works fine
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub enum WidgetValue{
    Integer32(i32),
    Unsized32(u32),
    CString(&'static str),
}

//lifetime error
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct DraggableInfo{
    parent: WidgetValue,
    index: WidgetValue,
    draggable_id: WidgetValue,
}
```

Error:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'de` due to conflicting requirements
```

Comment: I'm guessing based on not trying this myself but the likely cause of this error is that serde doesn't known how to deserialise into a static lifetime, since the data it is deserializing from isn't static.

Comment: Though I believe this is a follow up question from the last question you asked. Perhaps it would be best if you explained more about what your end goal is.

Comment: And as a side not I do not think you should derive copy on DraggableInfo.

Comment: @PiRocks why not derive ```Copy```?

Comment: `DraggableInfo` is at least 27 bytes, likely more due to alignment. By deriving copy you make a cost implicit, and end up passing by value everywhere instead of passing a reference.

Comment: @PiRocks do you agree with @jonasbb's recomendation to use ```CString(Cow<'static, str>)``` instead of ```CString(&'static str)```?

Comment: If it was me I would would add a lifetime parameter to the enum, and therefore the struct, but Cow may also work depending on the specifics. Based on your last question, you want to avoid String, but Cow smuggles in a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the lifetime error, by manually providing a bound on the `'de` lifetime during deserialization.
Due to the `&'static str` the enum `WidgetValue` only implements `Deserialize<'static>` since no other lifetime works to borrow a `&'static str`. This leads to an error for `DraggableInfo` since by default the `'de` lifetime is not constrained. With this manual bound you declare `'de` to outlive `'static`, making them equal.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(bound(deserialize = "'de: 'static"))]
pub struct DraggableInfo{
    parent: WidgetValue,
    index: WidgetValue,
    draggable_id: WidgetValue,
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub enum WidgetValue{
    Integer32(i32),
    Unsized32(u32),
    CString(&'static str),
}
```

You likely do not want to use it like this though, since you can only derive from `'static` data. You can redefine `CString` like this `CString(Cow<'static, str>)` to allow both static string literals and deserializing from non-static data.

Comment: This did  solve the lifetime error, but resulted in a new error that ```implementation of `Deserialize` is not general enough``` when I actually used ```DraggableInfo``` in a method. I created a new follow up question about this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68156340/implementation-of-serdedeserialize-is-not-general-enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68156340/implementation-of-serdedeserialize-is-not-general-enough)