# implementation of Serde::Deserialize is not general enough

Tags: rust, serde

I'm using [event_emmiter_rs](https://docs.rs/event-emitter-rs/0.1.4/event_emitter_rs/index.html) for event handling in my app. This library allows you to subscribe to events with callbacks and also fire those events. Events are in the form of (strings, value) and callbacks are in the form of closures that take in a value parameter. Values sent through the event callbacks must implement Serde::Deserialize. [We can see this here in the docs](https://docs.rs/event-emitter-rs/0.1.4/event_emitter_rs/struct.EventEmitter.html). So I created this simple setup:

```rust
use event_emitter_rs::EventEmitter;
use serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::borrow::Cow;

#[derive(Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(bound(deserialize = "'de: 'static"))]
//#[serde(bound(deserialize = "'de: 'a"))] using the 'a lifetime gives same error
pub struct DraggableInfo<'a>{
    parent: WidgetValue<'a>,
    index: WidgetValue<'a>,
    draggable_id: WidgetValue<'a>,
}

impl<'a> DraggableInfo<'a>{
    pub fn new(parent: &'static str, index: u32, draggable_id: &'static str)->Self{
        DraggableInfo{
            parent: WidgetValue::CString(Cow::Borrowed(parent)),
            index: WidgetValue::Unsized32(index),
            draggable_id: WidgetValue::CString(Cow::Borrowed(draggable_id)),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub enum WidgetValue<'a>{
    Integer32(i32),
    Unsized32(u32),
    CString(Cow<'a, str>)
}

fn main(){
    let mut event_emitter = EventEmitter::new();
    event_emitter.on("Print Draggable Value", |dragValue: DraggableInfo| {dbg!(dragValue);});
    event_emitter.emit("Print Draggable Value", DraggableInfo::new("root", 0, "layer 1")); 
}
```

But this results in error message:

```
error: implementation of `Deserialize` is not general enough
  --> src\main.rs:34:19
   |
34 |     event_emitter.on("Print Draggable Value", |dragValue: DraggableInfo| {dbg!(dragValue);});
   |                   ^^ implementation of `Deserialize` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `DraggableInfo<'_>` must implement `Deserialize<'0>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but `DraggableInfo<'_>` actually implements `Deserialize<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

I'm not sure what the `Deserialize<'0>` and `Deserialize<'1>` lifetimes the message refers to are, or exactly what the compiler means when it says the impl is "too general". How might I fix this error?

Comment: It's not general enough because of the `de: 'static` bound. This means you can only deserialize from static data i.e. data that lives for the entire life of the program. Presumably `event_emitter`  deals with data that is shorter lived than that and that is why it is complaining.

Comment: I thought this might be the case as well but using ```#[serde(bound(deserialize = "'de: 'a"))]``` gives the same error.

Comment: Well that is still a constraint. I'm not familiar with the crates you are using but you probably will need these structs to own their data, since the error is clear that the type needs to implement `Deserialize` for _any_ lifetime.

Comment: I'm not really sure what it would mean for a struct to own it's data in this situation. My understanding of lifetimes is pretty poor. Could you point me towards a relevant article/answer which illustrates your suggestion?

Comment: I mean use `String` instead of `Cow<'a, str>`.

Comment: Or you could implement `Deserialize` manually, so that all of the `Cow`s are `Cow::Owned`.

Comment: Why might you want to use one approach over the other?

Comment: I'm guessing you chose `Cow` for a reason. If you need it then that would be why, no?

Comment: @ANimator120 The code compiles fine if you remove the manual serde bound.  
  
@PeterHall `Cow`'s always deserialize to `Cow::Owned`. Only if you add `#[serde(borrow)]` does this change.

Comment: In the end I just went with using ```String``` instead of ```Cow``` or ```&'static str```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question dismissed in comments, but your specific problem was prominent in this line:

> `#[serde(bound(deserialize = "'de: 'static"))]`

As [Serde guide](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#trait-bounds) forewarns:

> Note that `<T> where T: Deserialize<'static>` is never what you want. Also `Deserialize<'de> + 'static` is never what you want. Generally writing `'static` anywhere near `Deserialize` is a sign of being on the wrong track. Use one of the above bounds instead.

Which should make practical sense: you'll never want to deserialize from 100% static data. Those `WidgetValue`s you have, they'll go in and out of scope (be created/destroyed) dynamically at runtime, right?..

But when you define the `CString` variant with a *reference* into the raw input buffer (the event payload from which deserialization happens) — you have to ensure that not a single `WidgetValue` ever outlives its input buffer. That's what Rust lifetimes are for, they encode machine-checked guarantees that Bad Things™ won't happen.

From comments again: the simple solution is to *own the data* instead of borrowing (referencing) it, i.e.

```
pub enum WidgetValue {
    Integer32(i32),
    Unsized32(u32),
    CString(String),
}
```

... but this simplicity will make you pay a performance cost, in heap allocations and gratuitous string copying whenever `WidgetValue`s are passed around. You'll lose the [zero-copy capacity](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html) supported by Serde. Not saying it's inherently bad; perhaps that price is okay for your application.

However, many programmers pick Rust for those applications where performance matters. Without compromise on safety, too. Which is to say: let's get our hands dirty.

---

Note: `Unsized32` is an oxymoron, you probably meant to write `Unsigned32`.

---

Note: in `DraggableInfo::new` signature, why require the borrowed string slices to have `'static` lifetime? That's way too strict. Simply `'a` will suffice.

---

> the error is clear that the type needs to implement Deserialize for *any* lifetime

Indeed; the [`.on` signature](https://docs.rs/event-emitter-rs/0.1.4/event_emitter_rs/struct.EventEmitter.html#method.on) does not have the `'de` as generic parameter:

```
pub fn on<F, T>(&mut self, event: &str, callback: F) -> String where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
    F: Fn(T) + 'static + Sync + Send,
```

Which implies a caller doesn't get to choose the lifetime. There's a chance that this is unintended, perhaps try asking the author or `event_emitter_rs` library; could be a subtle mistake, could be by design.

BTW: if you want to use things like [`serde_json::from_reader`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_reader.html) for deserializing truly dynamically in a stream — this whole zero-copy endeavor will not work out. That's expressed in that `DeserializeOwned` constraint. This fact is also mentioned in [the guide](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html), `For example when deserializing from an IO stream no data can be borrowed.`

At this point, I'm abandoning further research, because am visiting this question in the context of parsing JSON from a stream. This means I have no choice but to do `DeserializeOwned` (i.e. use owned `String`'s in my data structures instead of `&'a str`). Which also makes sense, because stream data is ephemeral, so borrowing from it simply won't work.